# Convert an Illustrator CC file to a layered PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, file-format, file-conversion

Is there a way to Convert an Illustrator CC file (.ai) to a layered PDF?

Comment: Are you asking this question because you don't have Illustrator? Try changing the file extension from `.ai` to `.pdf`.

Answer (score 3):

Illustrator files actually already contain PDF data. If you rename an illustrator file from `.ai` to `.pdf`, it opens as a PDF in PDF viewers, and the top level of layers of an Illustrator file opened as a PDF will ordinarily be treated as PDF layers.

**So actually, Illustrator files are *already* layered PDFs!** You don't even need Illustrator to make a basic conversion.

Note that PDF viewers only understand top level layers, not sub-layers; see below for more info. Also be aware that non-Adobe PDF previewers like web browsers and Mac Preview love to ignore your preferences and show hidden layers... **never send a client a PDF for review that contains a hidden layer!**

---

You can also export as a layered PDF without the Illustrator-specific stuff.

When you `File > Save As > PDF` from Illustrator, any layers you've created will become PDF layers visibile and toggleable in PDF viewers, *but only if the option **Create Acrobat Layers From Top Level Layers** is ticked* and the compatibility is set to 6+.

[More info from Adobe:](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/pdf-options.html)

> **Create Acrobat Layers From Top-level Layers.** Saves Illustrator’s top-level layers as Acrobat layers within the PDF file. This allows Adobe Acrobat 6, 7, and 8 users to generate multiple versions of the document from a single file.
>
> *note: This option is only available when Compatibility is set to Acrobat 6 (1.5), Acrobat 7 (1.6), and Acrobat 8 (1.7).*

You **don't** need "Preserve Illustrator Editing Capabilities" ticked to do this.

---

Note that PDFs can **only have one level of layers** unless you [do some hacky trickery](https://acrobatusers.com/forum/pdf-creation/pdf-layers-0/). So if your Illustrator file's Layers window looks like this:

[image]

... Layer 4 will get merged into Layer 2 in the PDF. If you want it to be a seperate layer in the PDF, make it a regular layer not a sub-layer.

Comment: Do most PDF viewers actually respect those layers? I've always used Acrobat so I don't know, it's just that Adobe specifically calls them "Acrobat Layers".

Comment: Depends on whether they support layers! I believe in general, browsers don't, Preview type programs don't (and love to show hidden layers... grrr...) but sophisticated PDF readers and printers do; but there's heaps of annoying variation and that's more of a software support http://superuser.com thing... in general if someone *needs* a layered PDF, presumably they have a specific purpose in mind and know what PDF processing software they're targetting and will be doing their own testing anyway

Comment: Makes sense. Just seems strange that Adobe would specifically call them "Acrobat Layers" and only mention Acrobat in the help docs, rather than a more generic "PDF Layers"